# How to assign all users access to a particular page in sitecollection?

Tags: permissions

We have 5 site collections. 1 is for internal users and other 4 are for respective clients. None of the clients have access to internal site collection.

There is an application page in layouts folder on the internal site collection, for this page we would like the others users to get access. What is the way? or is it that all users can access the application page?

Comment: Users with the "View Application Pages" permissions can view applications pages.  There are a few caveats, as stated in Grace Note's answer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824868/can-users-access-the-sharepoint-application-page-who-have-read-permissions

Comment: OK, do you mean that we create a group with 'view applications pages' permission, then, add users to this group, and they will be able to access all application pages in all site collections and all web applications?

Comment: It'll have to be done either per site collection or per site, depending on inheritance of permissions.  And as I mentioned, there are caveats, depending on the content on the application page.

Comment: The application page has got simple text, is there a way to put in a simple html page?

Comment: Then just create a group with 'View Application Pages' permission level on the site the application page is in.

Comment: But site setting is also an application page.

Comment: I'm assuming it's one of those caveats mentioned in the link I posted earlier.  I just tested it in my site.  A user with 'View Application Pages' cannot access Site Settings.

Comment: sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40144/deploy-application-page-on-a-web-application-not-the-farm-in-sharepoint-2010 check para 2 of answer by Jakobsen and my comment on it please

Comment: I've gathered enough information to post an answer.  I'll put what I have mentioned above, as well as answer your question in the link you just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a user to access an application page they must have 'View Application Pages' permission (available in the Read and View Only permission levels).  As stated in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979592.aspx) link, you can see that application pages are accessed by going to `{siteurl}/_layouts/{applicationpage}`.  The user needs 'View Application Pages' at the site located at `{siteurl}`.
So if a user does not have access to `http://myserver`, they will get access denied at `http://myserver/_layouts/applicationpage.aspx`.  However, if they have access (and that access gives them 'View Application Pages') to `http://myserver/subsite`, then they can open the application page at `http://myserver/subsite/_layouts/applicationpage.aspx`.

There are a few caveats, as stated in Grace Note's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824868/can-users-access-the-sharepoint-application-page-who-have-read-permissions).  You can configure permissions by defining the `RightsRequired` property.  The controls on the application page will also determine whether additional permissions will be required.  Here is Grace's example:

> For example, if you have a custom application page that has a field control associated with a specific list and item, if that control is in Edit mode then the user needs Edit permissions for that list and item in order to view the application page. It does not actually matter if this field control has anything to do with the list in question!

Comment: Ok so any user of any site in farm can view this page. Cool